# Probability: determine if $Z[n] = X[n] + Y[n]$ is WSS when $X[n]$ and $Y[n]$ are WSS

Tags: probability, random-variables, stationary-processes

> Determine if $Z[n] = X[n] + Y[n]$ is WSS when $X[n]$ and $Y[n]$ are WSS and every sample of $X[n]$ is independent of every sample of $Y[n]$.

---

Since both $X[n]$ and $Y[n]$ are WSS, $\mu_X[n] = \mu_1$, $\mu_Y[n] = \mu_2$, $E[X[n_1]X[n_2]] = g(\lvert n_1 - n_2\rvert)$ and $E[Y[n_1]Y[n_2]] = h(\lvert n_1 - n_2\rvert)$.

Then 
$$
E[Z[n]] = E[X[n]] + E[Y[n]] = \mu_1 + \mu_2
$$ 
which is a constant so condition one is met.
For condition two, we have
\begin{align}
E[Z[n_1]Z[n_2]] &= \cdots\\
&= E[X[n_1]X[n_2]] + E[Y[n_1]Y[n_2]] + E[X[n_1]Y[n_2]] + E[Y[n_1]X[n_2]]\\
&= g(\lvert n_1 - n_2\rvert) + h(\lvert n_1 - n_2\rvert) + E[X[n_1]Y[n_2]] + E[Y[n_1]X[n_2]]
\end{align}
I am not really sure with what to do with $E[X[n_1]Y[n_2]] + E[Y[n_1]X[n_2]]$. I am guessing the statement that $X$ and $Y$ are independent will play a role here but not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then:

$$E[XY] = E[X]E[Y]$$

Then:

$$E[Z[n_1]Z[n_2]] = g(\lvert n_1 - n_2\rvert) + h(\lvert n_1 - n_2\rvert) + 2\mu_1 \mu_2 = f(|n_1 - n_2|)$$

This met the WSS requirements on second order moment.

Comment: It doesn't matter that $f$ is affine?

Comment: It just depend on $|n_1 - n_2|$, and this is what WSS requires